# How can I get value in specific position in list form of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

NOTE:

Here is the reproducable expamle:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'index':[21144,64182,64184,64197,64198],'농약':['5. 방법/수단 : 농약_바스타_글루포시네이트암모늄' ,'5. 방법/수단 : 농약_바스타_글루포시네이트암모늄','5. 방법/수단 : 농약_확타_글루포시네이트암모늄' ,'5. 방법/수단 : 농약_모름_글루포시네이트','5. 방법/수단 : 농약_바로바로_글루포시네이트']})
df.set_index('index',inplace=True,append=False)
pes_df = df['농약'].str.split('_',expand=False)
pes_df
```

I have a list form of column in pandas dataframe. Here is the sample dataset

```
21144                                                                                                      [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 바스타, 글루포시네이트암모늄 ]
64182                                                                                                      [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 바스타, 글루포시네이트암모늄 ]
64184                                                                                                       [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 확타, 글루포시네이트암모늄 ]
64197                                                                                                          [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 모름, 글루포시네이트 ]
64198                                                                                                        [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 바로바로, 글루포시네이트 ]
64200                                                                                                   [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 레드샷, 글리포세이트이소프로필아민 ]
64205                                                                                                             [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 모름, 비펜트린 ]
64212                                                                                                           [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 그라목손, 파라콰트 ]
64219                                                                                                          [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 판데스, 사이퍼메트린 ]
64253                                                                                                [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 테라도플러스, 글리포세이트이소프로필아민 ]
64254                                                                                                   [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 근사미, 글리포세이트이소프로필아민 ]
64294                                                                                                               [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 모름, 모름 ]
64295                                                                                                   [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 푸레쎈, 글리포세이트이소프로필아민 ]
64301                                                                                                         [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 시반토, 플루피라디퓨론 ]
64336                                                                                                   [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 푸레쎈, 글리포세이트이소프로필아민 ]
64350                                                                                           [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 농약, 인바이오글라신, 글리포세이트이소프로필아민 ]
```

I want to manipulate the second column of this list. For instance, replacing 모름 -> 999

the output would be like this

```
21144                                                                                                      [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 바스타, 글루포시네이트암모늄 ]
64182                                                                                                      [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 바스타, 글루포시네이트암모늄 ]
64184                                                                                                       [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 확타, 글루포시네이트암모늄 ]
64197                                                                                                          [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 999, 글루포시네이트 ]
64198                                                                                                        [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 바로바로, 글루포시네이트 ]
64200                                                                                                   [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 레드샷, 글리포세이트이소프로필아민 ]
64205                                                                                                             [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 999, 비펜트린 ]
64212                                                                                                           [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 그라목손, 파라콰트 ]
64219                                                                                                          [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 판데스, 사이퍼메트린 ]
64253                                                                                                [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 테라도플러스, 글리포세이트이소프로필아민 ]
64254                                                                                                   [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 근사미, 글리포세이트이소프로필아민 ]
64294                                                                                                               [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 999, 모름 ]
64295                                                                                                   [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 푸레쎈, 글리포세이트이소프로필아민 ]
64301                                                                                                         [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 시반토, 플루피라디퓨론 ]
64336                                                                                                   [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 푸레쎈, 글리포세이트이소프로필아민 ]
64350                                                                                           [5. 방법/수단 : 농약, 농약, 인바이오글라신, 글리포세이트이소프로필아민 ]
```

and I would like to join it with special letter '_'.

so the outcome would be like this for the index 21144

```
21144                                                                                                      5. 방법/수단 : 농약_바스타_글루포시네이트암모늄
```

Comment: I've tried pes_df[1] but it cause the `KeyError: 1`

Comment: Did you try `df.iloc[0,1]` and adjust as needed to get the desired result?

Comment: @Mech IndexingError: Too many indexers caused

Comment: What's the difference between the first output and the second output and what do you mean by joining them with the special letter? BTW, to index a row by the order, you should use pes_df.iloc[1] instead.

Comment: make minimal and reproducible example and provide code for answer. if example has list form of column, need example code to make example dataframe. read following post to make example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Panda kim I added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

i make minimal and reproducible example

```
data = ['method_Basta_glufosinate', 'method_unknown_ammonium', 'method_unknown_ammonium']
df = pd.Series(data).to_frame('col1')
```

df

```
    col1
0   method_Basta_glufosinate
1   method_unknown_ammonium
2   method_unknown_ammonium
```

---

**Code**

unknown -> 999

you don need make list for changing your `unknown` to `999`

use `str.replace`

```
df['col1'].str.replace('unknown', '999')
```

result:

```
0    method_Basta_glufosinate
1         method_999_ammonium
2         method_999_ammonium
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Are there any additional reasons for needing list? then use following code:

```
df['col1'].apply(lambda x: [i if i != 'unknown' else 999 for i in x.split('_')])
```

output:

```
0    [method, Basta, glufosinate]
1         [method, 999, ammonium]
2         [method, 999, ammonium]
Name: col1, dtype: object
```